# vs-code-extension api gives error TS2403 on MACOS Catalina

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

I am trying to run the: "Your First Extension" code in https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension on macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

However, when I run the extension the Host does not launch and if I compile the project I get errors (details below)

I suspect is related to some unmet dependencies related to the type files but I am not sure where to look. I searched all over and I could not find and answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!
Armando

Here are the details:

```
> helloworld@0.0.1 compile
> tsc -p ./

../../node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/events.d.ts:91:42 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Node'.
91   element: Document | Element | Window | Node,
                                            ~~~~
../../node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/events.d.ts:96:44 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Node'.

96     element: Document | Element | Window | Node,
                                              ~~~~
../../node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/events.d.ts:102:39 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Node'.

102   node: Document | Element | Window | Node,
                                          ~~~~

../../node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/events.d.ts:108:44 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Node'.
108     element: Document | Element | Window | Node,
                                               ~~~~

../../node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/pretty-dom.d.ts:8:23 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Node'.

8   filterNode?: (node: Node) => boolean
                        ~~~~

../../node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/pretty-dom.d.ts:12:19 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLDocument'.

12   dom?: Element | HTMLDocument,
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/pretty-dom.d.ts:17:19 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLDocument'.

17   dom?: Element | HTMLDocument,
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/screen.d.ts:11:31 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLDocument'.

11     element?: Array<Element | HTMLDocument> | Element | HTMLDocument,
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/screen.d.ts:11:57 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLDocument'.

11     element?: Array<Element | HTMLDocument> | Element | HTMLDocument,
                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/screen.d.ts:19:49 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLDocument'.

19   logTestingPlaygroundURL: (element?: Element | HTMLDocument) => void
                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/wait-for.d.ts:6:29 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MutationObserverInit'.

6   mutationObserverOptions?: MutationObserverInit
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:35:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'beforeEach' must be of type 'HookFunction', but here has type 'Lifecycle'.

35 declare var beforeEach: jest.Lifecycle;
               ~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts:2642:13
    2642 declare var beforeEach: Mocha.HookFunction;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~
    'beforeEach' was also declared here.

../../node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:37:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'afterEach' must be of type 'HookFunction', but here has type 'Lifecycle'.

37 declare var afterEach: jest.Lifecycle;
               ~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts:2660:13
    2660 declare var afterEach: Mocha.HookFunction;
                     ~~~~~~~~~
    'afterEach' was also declared here.

../../node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:38:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'describe' must be of type 'SuiteFunction', but here has type 'Describe'.

38 declare var describe: jest.Describe;
               ~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts:2676:13
    2676 declare var describe: Mocha.SuiteFunction;
                     ~~~~~~~~
    'describe' was also declared here.

../../node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:40:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'xdescribe' must be of type 'PendingSuiteFunction', but here has type 'Describe'.

40 declare var xdescribe: jest.Describe;
               ~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts:2697:13
    2697 declare var xdescribe: Mocha.PendingSuiteFunction;
                     ~~~~~~~~~
    'xdescribe' was also declared here.

../../node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:41:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'it' must be of type 'TestFunction', but here has type 'It'.

41 declare var it: jest.It;
               ~~

  node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts:2711:13
    2711 declare var it: Mocha.TestFunction;
                     ~~
    'it' was also declared here.

../../node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:43:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'xit' must be of type 'PendingTestFunction', but here has type 'It'.

43 declare var xit: jest.It;
               ~~~

  node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts:2732:13
    2732 declare var xit: Mocha.PendingTestFunction;
                     ~~~
    'xit' was also declared here.

../../node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:44:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'test' must be of type 'TestFunction', but here has type 'It'.

44 declare var test: jest.It;
               ~~~~

  node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts:2725:13
    2725 declare var test: Mocha.TestFunction;
                     ~~~~
    'test' was also declared here.


Found 18 errors in 5 files.

Errors  Files
     4  ../../node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/events.d.ts:91
     3  ../../node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/pretty-dom.d.ts:8
     3  ../../node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/screen.d.ts:11
     1  ../../node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/wait-for.d.ts:6
     7  ../../node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:35

My node and npm versions are:
node --version
v16.13.1
npm --version
8.11.0

The packages.json and tsconfig.json files generated by YO are

package.json:
{
  "name": "helloworld",
    "displayName": "HelloWorld",
    "description": "",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^1.67.0"
    },
    "categories": [
        "Other"
    ],
    "activationEvents": [
        "onCommand:helloworld.helloWorld"
    ],
    "main": "./out/extension.js",
    "contributes": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "helloworld.helloWorld",
                "title": "Hello World"
            }
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "vscode:prepublish": "npm run compile",
        "compile": "tsc -p ./",
        "watch": "tsc -watch -p ./",
        "pretest": "npm run compile && npm run lint",
        "lint": "eslint src --ext ts",
        "test": "node ./out/test/runTest.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/vscode": "^1.67.0",
        "@types/glob": "^7.2.0",
        "@types/mocha": "^9.1.1",
        "@types/node": "14.x",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.21.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.21.0",
        "eslint": "^8.14.0",
        "glob": "^8.0.1",
        "mocha": "^9.2.2",
        "typescript": "^4.6.4",
        "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.1.3"
    }
}

tsconfig.json:

{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "ES2020",
        "outDir": "out",
        "lib": [
            "ES2020"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "src",
        "strict": true   /* enable all strict type-checking options */
        /* Additional Checks */
        // "noImplicitReturns": true, /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
        // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true, /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
        // "noUnusedParameters": true,  /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    }
}
```

Comment: Could be not all required node modules are installed. Run `npm i` in the root of the project, then try again to build it.

Comment: Mike, thanks for your suggestion. I forgot to mention that I did run `npm i` in the root of the project.  

Something interesting to mention is that I downloaded the samples and ran the equivalent w/o `npm i` and the host launched and although it complained about node_modules not being present, the extension worked. I guess it just used the file from the `/out` directory

Comment: I would suggest deleting the ```node_modules``` folder and the ```package-lock.json``` file, then rerunning ```npm install```. If that does not fix it I would advise you to do the same again and run ```npm cache clean –force```, then run ```npm install```